# how to implement "email to add/post" function similar to Evernote, Remeber the milk, blogger, etc?

Tags: asp.net, email, addition

many website/apps now have function to take incoming emails and add to backend datastore, etc. E.g Evernote, Blogger, you can send an email to specified email address and your note/post will be added. How do they implement this?

What I have done:

1. create a special email box.
2. let user to send email in certain format.
3. then in ASP.NET, read incoming emails periodically using a dummy page and a timer.
4. then parse email and process information inside.

My questions are:

1. Is one special email box enough or create email box for each individual users?
2. Is there a universal format? e.g "@2012-09-03" in subject stands for time or something?
3. Is there a better way to actively monitor email box, detect unread emails in specified frequency or real time?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really missing here is security.
How do you validate who the sender is?

With emails its easy to impersonate someone else.
While there are methods to securely know this(DomainKeys), not everyone uses them.

Blogger tries to mitigate this risk by asking you to specify a secret email address that you will use to mail them.

One special inbox is definitely not enough.

For the date format, you could use the [ISO date format](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date).
This is also used by microdata format for time, so it should be easy to display, and be [readable to search engines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035) too.

```
<time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2012-10-11T19:00-08:00">11 Oct 2012, 7PM</time>
```

To receive your mails, take a look at [MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/).
It does have a

> New message arrival notification support (IDLE command)

So you wouldn't have to poll the server all the time.

Comment: Thnaks nunespascal. For Blogger, do you mean they use something like blogger+userid@blogger.com, one emailbox for each user? For format, I acutally thinking of grammer, what part of the email will be used as title, which part will be used as date, location, etc, e.g @2012-09-03 is time, #central station is the location.

Comment: I am saying that, keep that email id big and unpredictable(yes one for each user). It would offer some obfuscation from a malicious user posting data to someone else's account. The grammar is entirely your call, since only you will be parsing it.